# Authorised ID card for entry into airport

Tags: air-travel, airports, india

My grand son studying 3rd Std is with us, with his parents away in Bangalore. He has an expired-passport and a school ID card. He has no Aadhaar card yet. For entry into airports, what proof should I carry for him? Will a School photo ID, or a notary  or a certificate by (Central/State ) Gztd Officer serve the purpose?

Comment: @ KC Rao What do you mean by ‘entry into airports’?

Comment: @Traveller Indian airports generally have a check at the door to enter the airport terminal.

Answer (score 3):

This [notification from the Bureau of Civil Aviation Security](http://www.bcasindia.nic.in/law/AC%2015-2017-listofidproof.pdf) says:

> 3. There shall not be any requirement of identity proof in respect of Infant/Minor accompanied by their parents/guardian who is a bonafide
>      passenger having a valid identity proof as listed above. However, an
>      unaccompanied minor shall be required to produce a valid identity
>      proof as listed above.

If you accompany the child, it looks like they won't need an ID card for entering the airport. It also says:

> 4. In case of a passenger who for some valid reasons is not in a position to produce any of the above-listed photo identity proofs, the
>      Identity Certificate issued by a Group' A' Gazetted Officer of the
>      Central/State Government on his official letterhead with passenger's
>      photograph duly attested will be valid for this purpose.

The list of acceptable identity proofs (given in item (2)) is:

> 1. Passport;
> 2. Voter Photo Identity card issued by Election Commission of India;
> 3. Aadhaar or m-Aadhaar issued by Unique Identification Authority of India (UIDAI);
> 4. PAN Card issued by Income Tax Department;
> 5. Driving License issued by RTO;
> 6. Service Photo Identity Card issued by State/Central Government, Public Sector Undertakings, local bodies or Public Limited Companies;
> 7. Student Photo Identity Cards issued by Government Institutions/Government recognized Educational Institutions;
> 8. Nationalized Bank Passbook with attested Photograph;
> 9. Pension card / Pension documents having photograph of the passenger;
> 10. Disability Photo ID Card/handicapped medical certificate issued by the respective State/UT Governments/Administrations